# Override form using PHPTemplate

Tags: drupal, templates, forms, themes

I was wondering how I should override the way a form looks in Drupal 7 using PHPTemplate. I have some difficulties displaying all the information on my page.

I have a page with a form and some miscellaneous information.

I have tried:

foo.module

```
function foo_add_form($form, &$form_state, $foo) {

  ...

  $form['#theme'] = 'foo_add';

  return $form;
}

function foo_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'foo_add' => array(
      'template' => 'foo-add',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}
```

foo-add.tpl.php

```
<?php
    // First form
    print drupal_render_children($form);
?>
<!-- Miscellaneous information -->
    <div id="links">
        <ul>...</ul>
        <form action="#" method="post" id="second-form">
            <fieldset id="i-want">
             ...
                </fieldset>
                    ...
            </form>
    </div>
```

At the moment the form and miscellaneous information are being displayed. However, the 2nd form (id="second-form") is being removed somehow. I can see it in the source, but when I inspect the element with chrome/firefox, I can no longer see the form element. I can see the div, ul and fieldset tags though.

Has anybody done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you wouldn't add to the form at the theme layer. Instead, you'd use a custom module, implementing [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to modify the form.

Comment: The form is made in my custom module so wouldn't it be strange to implement hook_form_alter to modify the form? At the moment it sort of works the way I described it above. The only problem is that the second form tag is somehow removed after rendering (javascript?).